# Проблема с буквой "Й" в UTF-8

Tags: linux, mac, hex, diff

Пытаюсь сравнить два файла, оба содержат список файлов/папок, один сделан на маке, другой на linux.
`diff` показывает разницу где ее на первый взгляд нет.
Перевод в hex режим показал что одна и та же буква (визуально это `й`)
в одной системе сформировалась след. символом `d0b9` а в другой `d0b8`.
Может кто знает почему ? и как сравнивать в таком случае ?

Comment: Может у вас что то с визуальным отображением ? потому как d0b8 - это "и", а d0b9 - "й"

Comment: В этом то и дело что выглядит то это вот так http://bit.ly/1PUMPvn а вот так в hex
http://bit.ly/1OTrq75

Comment: Я не знаю, что это за средство отображения, откуда оно показало эти буквы. Вы файлы в чем нибудь другом посмотрите, да хоть редактором каким нибудь текстовым. Но d0b8 это "и", без вариантов.

Comment: это просто Vim :) но мысль хорошая сейчас попробую открыть чем то иным... и так в хроме к примеру тоже й отображается )

Comment: Во вотором случае у вас 'й' закодировано как два отдельных символа - 'и' и "шляпка" (COMBINING BREVE). Об этом можно почитать здесь: http://habrahabr.ru/post/262679/

Comment: @user1016265 С учетом вышесказанного insolor вам надо файл с кривой буквой й прогонять через sed: `cat файл | sed "s/\xD0\xB8\xCC\x86/\xD0\xB9/g"`

Comment: @insolor Думаю вам стоит опубликовать это как ответ. Конечно с  кратким пересказом того, что на хабре и можете добавить в ответ тот `sed` что я выше написал.

Comment: @insolor круто очень! Спасибо

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Буква "й" может быть кодирована в unicode двумя способами: как один символ - собственно, "й" ([Cyrillic Small Letter Short I](http://unicode-table.com/en/0439/)), и как два символа - "и" ([Cyrillic Small Letter I](http://unicode-table.com/en/0438/)) и [Combining Breve](http://unicode-table.com/en/0306/) ("шляпка"). Это может создавать определённые проблемы при сравнении и поиске текста.

Подробнее можно почитать в этой статье:
[Хабрахабр: «Й» вам не «и» краткое! О важности нормализации Unicode](http://habrahabr.ru/post/262679/)

В вашем случае можно файл с "разложенной" буквой "й" перед сравнением прогнать через sed с помощью следующей команды:

```
cat файл | sed "s/\xD0\xB8\xCC\x86/\xD0\xB9/g"
```

(предложено участником [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike))