# сдвиг указателя файла

Tags: c

У меня был код который делал реверс каждой строки файла в однобайтной кодировке.
Теперь понадобилось сделать это для UTF-8.
Переписал под  wide char(код ниже).
Она так же реверсит строки, но некоторые символы теряются.
Понимаю, что проблема c функциями fseek в конце тела цикла. 
Но сам решить ее не могу.

```
#define NULL_TERMINATOR '\0'
#define NEW_LINE '\n'
 int main()
 {
   size_t i = 0;
       file = _wfopen(L"rev.txt", L"r+, ccs=UTF-8");
        wchar_t b[4096]{ NULL_TERMINATOR };
        while ((fgetws(b, sizeof(b), file)) != NULL)
        {
            if (b[wcslen(b) - 1] == NEW_LINE)
            {
                b[wcslen(b) - 1] = NULL_TERMINATOR;
                wcsrev(b);
                b[wcslen(b)] = NEW_LINE;
            }
            else wcsrev(b);
            fseek(file, i, SEEK_SET);
            int t=fwrite(b, wcslen(b)*2, count, file);
            i += wcslen(b)*2+3;
            fseek(file, i, SEEK_SET);
        }
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Думается, что Ваша проблема в том, что Вы считаете все символы utf-8 двухбайтовыми.

Comment: У файл заполнен кириллическими  символами, а в байт они не влезут.

Comment: @Kirill21 Только вот пробелы, знаки препинания и латинские символы при этом остаются однобайтовыми. не прочитав первый байт символа невозможно предсказать какой он длины. вообще utf-8 символы могут быть до 5 байт длиной

Comment: У Вас есть кириллический текст и Вы действительно считаете, что все символы utf-8 в нем двухбайтовые?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474663/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8/474720#474720

Comment: ... и тут он понял, что его задачка оказалась не так уж и проста :) ...

Comment: @MaxZS Вы не даете ответа по теме,а просто оставляете не несущие пользы никому коментарии. Нет,я так не считаю.Так как уже было сказано выше знаки пробелов и латинские символы однобайтные.

Comment: @Mike UTF-8 символ может быть до 6 байт размером (не до 5).

Comment: Я изначально Вам написал, в чем Ваша проблема. Но Вы этого не поняли. Вы действительно считали все символы двухбайтовыми. Я еще раз повторил свой вопрос во втором комментарии, так как Вы не дали четкого своего понимания в своем комментарии. Мой второй комментарий пришел практически одновременно с комментарием Mike. И я не стану забирать у него ответ (давать свой такой же) - это не этично.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо  думаю это решит мою проблему

Comment: @alexolut А мне кажется, что в utf-8 вообще не заложено ограничение размера символа. Из википедии: `Алгоритм UTF-8 технически позволяет записывать код любой длины. Но для эффективной и надёжной работы алгоритма необходимо ограничение длины кода. Действующий стандарт Unicode 6.х предполагает использование кода до 21-го бита, то есть до четырех байт в UTF-8.`

Comment: @MaxZS Эмм, может я вас удивлю, но когда я редактировал свой текстовый файл в notepade++ там внизу есть количество символов. И когда печатаешь кириллический символ то к общей сумме добовляется 2, латиница и знаки препинания 1, вроде как для иероглифов идет число 3. Это так ,к слову, про двухбайтные символы и мое отношение к ним.

Comment: @Kirill21 Кстати, Abyx прав, при реверсе вас могут ждать и другие проблемы, типа комбинированных символов. например буква Й http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481050/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%99-%D0%B2-utf-8  И это скажите спасибо, что язык Русский, utf-8 позволяет к символу приписать до 3х комбинационных знаков и практически все библиотеки считают их за отдельные символы. далеко ходить не надо, javascript на комбинированную Й дает длину 2 символа

Comment: Считаю вопрос закрытым.Свою проблему понял. Всем спасибо за ответы:)