# Баг с буквой "Й"

Tags: php

Заметил, что в некоторых непонятных случаях php считает букву "Й" не 1 символом, а двумя. Из-за этого возникают разные неприятности, например при переборе символов функцией mb_substr. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Я использовал mb_substr везде

Comment: @vp_arth На самом деле Й может быть представлена как одним (потому как он есть в таблице) так и двумя символами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481109/194569

Comment: И как это исправить в php?

Comment: @АлексКирсанов Если вам в тексте попались Й состоящие из двух codepoint то никакой mb_ вас не спасет. единственный путь - заменить заранее в тексте кривые Й на нормальные примерно такой же регуляркой как приведена по той ссылке

Comment: Mike прав. Есть такое понятие, как [Unicode Normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). В PHP есть класс [Normalizer](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.normalizer.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно применять нормализацию:

```
$i1 = "\xd0\xb9"; // й
$i2 = "\xd0\xb8\xcc\x86"; // и с дужкой

echo $i1, ' ', strlen($i1), ' ', mb_strlen($i1), ' ', mb_strlen(Normalizer::normalize($i1, Normalizer::NFC)),  "\n";
echo $i2, ' ', strlen($i2), ' ', mb_strlen($i2), ' ', mb_strlen(Normalizer::normalize($i2, Normalizer::NFC)), "\n";
```

> й 2 1 1
>   й 4 2 1

после нормализации, композитная версия й превращается в простую.

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/WefQB)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!