# Скрипт python не видит символ "й" на Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

```
OSError: MoviePy error: the file /root/snegurochka/materials/sound/boy/Дмитрий.mp3 could not be found!
Please check that you entered the correct path.
```

Важный момент, что все отлично работает со всеми другими именами, которые не содержат букву "й".
Не понимаю в чем может быть проблема. Конечно можно просто вместо "й" написать "и", но в данном случае такой вариант невозможен.
На системе установлен русский и если вывести `ls` в директории с файлами, то все имена, в том числе и с буквами "й", отображаются корректно.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Проблема с буквой "Й" в UTF-8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/481050/1365)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой статье все разложено по полочкам: https://habr.com/ru/post/262679/

Проблема решилась переименованием с нормализацией юникода:

```
from unicodedata import normalize
import os
import sys
import os.path



directory_1 = '/root/snegurochka/materials/sound/comments'
inputnames_1 = os.listdir(directory_1)
inputnames_1.sort()
inputnames_1 = inputnames_1[1:] # это для удаления вспомогательного файла .DS на маке
for x in inputnames_1:
    # print(str(x[:-4]))
    # file.write(x[:-4] + '\n')
    nx = normalize('NFC', x[:-4])
    # print(str(nx))
    os.rename(f"/root/snegurochka/materials/sound/comments/{x[:-4]}.mp3", f"/root/snegurochka/materials/sound/comments/{str(nx)}.mp3")
```